# Centroid of a paraboloid.

Tags: integration, centroid

Consider the paraboloid given by $x^2+y^2=az$ where $a>0$ with constant density $\rho$. We are told to calculate the volume enclosed in the above paraboloid between $z=0$ and $z=h$. My attempt is $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_0^h\int_0^{\sqrt{az}}rdrdzd\theta$$ which gave me $$ V=\frac{\pi ah^2}{2} $$ Which doesn't look correct based on the words of google. We continue further to derive the center of mass. $$ c = \frac{1}{V}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_0^h\int_0^{\sqrt{az}}r^2drdzd\theta $$ which gives the point at which the center of mass resides as $$x=y=0, z=\frac{8\sqrt{ah}}{15}$$ which certainly doesn't look right according to google. Many thanks

Comment: Looks right to me.

Comment: Many thanks kind sir! But for some reason google said the square term was on $a$ as opposed to $h$? Is this just a notation thing? Also, it gave the center of mass at $\frac{2}{3}h$?

Comment: (I think you want $dr dz d\theta$ in your integrals.)

Comment: Ah yes, my bad. Will edit that in now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation of the volume looks fine, but the center of mass should be at $\frac{2h}{3}$:

$\displaystyle \;\;\overline{z}=\frac{1}{V}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\sqrt{ah}}\int_{r^2/a}^h z\cdot r\;dzdrd\theta=\frac{1}{V}\cdot2\pi\int_0^{\sqrt{ah}}\left[r\cdot\frac{z^2}{2}\right]_{r^2/a}^h dr$

$\displaystyle=\frac{2\pi}{V}\int_0^{\sqrt{ah}}\left(\frac{h^2}{2}r-\frac{r^5}{2a^2}\right)dr=\frac{2\pi}{V}\left[\frac{h^2r^2}{4}-\frac{r^6}{12a^2}\right]_0^{\sqrt{ah}}=\frac{2\pi}{V}\left(\frac{ah^3}{4}-\frac{ah^3}{12}\right)$

$\displaystyle=\frac{2\pi}{V}\cdot\frac{ah^3}{6}=\frac{4}{ah^2}\cdot\frac{ah^3}{6}=\frac{2h}{3}.$

Comment: I understand this approach, but why is it not possible to have the limits of z fixed from $0\to h$, but allow r to vary from $0\to \sqrt{za}$?

Comment: That will work, too, but I think you wanted zr as the integrand instead of $r^2$.

Comment: Yes of course! Many thanks for your help! That method worked also!

Comment: You're welcome; thanks for letting me know it worked that way, too.